Is there a way to automatically mark up a PDF with the target page number opposite each link?
I often have a situation where I have a PDF which contains pages with text, and some words of the text have links which point to other pages within the same PDF. Is there a way to get the page number pointed to by each link to appear opposite the link (i.e. same Y value as link and an X value almost up to the right hand edge of the page) so that someone using a hardcopy of the PDF (who therefore cannot click on links) can see which page number the link points to so that they can turn to that page?
I have looked at using Adobe Acrobat, PDF X-Change Editor, Nitro PDF, and Foxit but none have a facility which could do this.
TL;DR If you are interested in the wider background (not necessary to understand the question but just out of interest) the background is legal procedure. At a court hearing there is a collection of documents combined into a single bookmarked PDF. Some of the documents are witness statements. Most of the documents are ordinary letters, emails, invoices, photos etc. from the past which happen to be relevant to what the court case is about. Statements will refer to specific documents but the documents they refer to won't be positioned  immediately following each statement but will be scattered throughout the PDF (because they are required to be in a specific order). To make it easy when reading through statements, every time a statement mentions a document the words referencing that document are hyperlinked to the document. So far so straightforward. But not everyone uses the PDF. Some people just use a printout of the PDF and so can't use the hyperlinks. To cater for them the PDF page number of each document hyperlinked to in a statement is written opposite the hyperlinked words.

PDF has many "stack language" concepts thus the link on a page is not always in the page. Not in this case but a piece of page text will link to an external site (same as here in HTML) thus there is no stored list of pages with such links to query. For other external links and links in pages those links are not stored within pages but in random object numbers at random addresses thus again there is no single list they are queried and constructed at run time when a page is displayed (in effect same as a HTML.css "hot spot") in tracker there is an option to see the list of found links and export

Basically from your questions point of view each sequential page has NO WAY way of knowing how many links are notionally from or goto that page. you need to write such a function that trawls the file sorts the order and writes to each link a blue box around the link (as many readers do) and then sorts where they might possibly fit on a secondary added page using a full PDF editor. Acrobat Pro custom plug-in ? or Tracker SDK ?

The way links are stored in a PDF means there is no in page "Anchor". the simplest way to see that is look at how pages are described. So for simplicity I have written this 3 page file, where the top right position just like a flipbook will go to next page.

Clearly "nothing" is visible (it is just a hot spot) and all page entries have nothing in their code. Here they are where page "contents" are 9 10 and 11 but all say /Length 0 (nothing to show) so we need to read and export the linking objects, before adding anything to the file.
%PDF-1.7
1 0 obj<</Names<</Dests 2 0 R>>/Pages 3 0 R/Type/Catalog>>endobj
3 0 obj<</Count 3/Kids[5 0 R 6 0 R 4 0 R]/Type/Pages>>endobj

5 0 obj<</Annots[7 0 R]/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 9 0 R>>endobj
7 0 obj<</A<</D[6 0 R/XYZ null null null]/S/GoTo>>/Border[0 0 0]/C[0 0 0]/F 4/NM(1265dfdf-e57e-4f60-94f4dc2d4d08c9aa)/P 5 0 R/Rect[450 750 595 842]/Subtype/Link/Type/Annot>>endobj
9 0 obj<</Length 0>>
stream
endstream
endobj

6 0 obj<</Annots[8 0 R]/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 10 0 R>>endobj
8 0 obj<</A<</D(Page3)/S/GoTo>>/Border[0 0 0]/C[0 0 0]/F 4/NM(7f204e9d-9862-4269-9776358454c37864)/P 6 0 R/Rect[450 750 595 842]/Subtype/Link/Type/Annot>>endobj
10 0 obj<</Length 0>>
stream
endstream
endobj
2 0 obj<</Names[(Page3)[4 0 R/XYZ 0 842 null]]>>endobj

4 0 obj<</MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 11 0 R>>endobj
11 0 obj<</Length 0>>
stream
endstream
endobj

xref
0 12
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000782 00000 n 
0000000074 00000 n 
0000000838 00000 n 
0000000136 00000 n 
0000000468 00000 n 
0000000242 00000 n 
0000000575 00000 n 
0000000422 00000 n 
0000000736 00000 n 
0000000931 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 12/Root 1 0 R/ID[<4657E6C7218E18DED2570E82964D21E2><9946E25234503908D6698FAD5FE9296F>]>>
startxref
0978
%%EOF

Links Output as a table will look like:
Title,"Modification Date","Placement Page","Link Rectangle","Border Color","Border Style","Border Width","Highlight Type",Actions
<None>,,1,"450,750,595,842",#000000,Solid,0,Invert,"goto:{2, XYZ, 15}"
<None>,,2,"450,750,595,842",#000000,Solid,0,Invert,"goto:{3, XYZ, 12, 0.000, 842.000}"

The writing of the output could be added to the right of the top right corners by easily widen the pages from 595 to say 842 (same as page height) otherwise the numbers would be meaningless as disturbed by injecting more pages.
The problem now as the pages have no annotations as text we will need to add many additional complex editor resources such as fonts and their placements and mapping etc, Expanding the file significantly more than it is.
The common method to export and import to a PDF is the compatible FDF file format. so the export of goto's may seem complex as can vary but there are only a few target parts.
Here is the export (simplified to single lines for brevity).
%FDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj<</FDF<</Annots [2 0 R 3 0 R]/F (source.pdf)/ID [<4657E6C7218E18DED2570E82964D21E2> <9946E25234503908D6698FAD5FE9296F>]/UF (source.pdf)>>
/Type /Catalog>>
endobj
2 0 obj<</A <</D [1 /XYZ null null null]/S /GoTo>>/Border [0 0 0]/C [0 0 0]/F 4/NM (1265dfdf-e57e-4f60-94f4dc2d4d08c9aa)/Page 0/Rect [450 750 595 842]/Subtype /Link/Type /Annot>>endobj
3 0 obj<</A <</D (Page3)/S /GoTo>>/Border [0 0 0]/C [0 0 0]/F 4/NM (7f204e9d-9862-4269-9776358454c37864)/Page 1/Rect [450 750 595 842]/Subtype /Link/Type /Annot>>endobj
trailer
<</Root 1 0 R>>
%%EOF

The key points are the word goto and page numbers in a PDF ALWAYS start at 0 for first page.
Now we can replace that export with a varied import along the lines of
%FDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj<</FDF <</Annots [2 0 R 3 0 R]/F (source.pdf)/ID [<4657E6C7218E18DED2570E82964D21E2> <9946E25234503908D6698FAD5FE9296F>]/UF (source.pdf)>>/Type /Catalog>>endobj
2 0 obj<</Type/Annot/Subtype/FreeText/BS<</W 0>>/DS (font-family:Helvetica New;font-size:10pt;color:#000000;)/F 4/IT /FreeTextTypewriter/Subj (Typewriter)
/DA (0 0 0 rg /F1 10 Tf)/Page 0/Rect [550 788 595 810]/Contents (Page 2)
>>endobj
3 0 obj<</Type/Annot/Subtype/FreeText/BS<</W 0>>/DS (font-family:Helvetica New;font-size:10pt;color:#000000;)/F 4/IT /FreeTextTypewriter/Subj (Typewriter)
/DA (0 0 0 rg /F1 10 Tf)/Page 1/Rect [550 788 595 810]/Contents (Page 3)
>>endobj
trailer
<</Root 1 0 R>>
%%EOF

And the desired result are comments in the margins

The task is thus as simple as edit the annots export into a desired annots import, using any programming language. These were done in MS Notepad but Notepad++ would be more suitable with its macro functions.
Many PDF users would use more complex dependencies such as Python for editing combined with say PyMuPDF for the PDF editing. However most Operating systems can command line run editing plain text. The main issue is decompressing the PDF into its historic text format. All those perhaps could be done with command line PDFtk.
If you open the FDF by select or command line with PDFXedit. It will automatically load the PDF and add the annotations for you.


You can see the same ability in Acrobat if you have ANY suitable PDF file for the import. Save the second FDF as I wrote it, and open it with Acrobat Reader. Which will ask for a source PDF and warn you about security of opening an unknown import. You should see the comments appear top right of page 1 and page 2. Just as they would with any source, since comments are not attached to any anchor object and nor are hyperlinks. ALL such objects are simply areas that link TO a pages content ,thus dont come from an object in a page.

The answer looks more complicated than I was expecting and I wonder whether the way I worded the question might have been misleading so I have amended it to make clear that the PDF already contains text.

It all looks very complicated. I was hoping there might be some commercially available app which did this.

Adding a page number in the margin is a very common requirement in the legal industry. Pre-existing documents are combined together in a single PDF. These are pre-existing evidential documents, not documents created by the lawyer so the lawyer cannot simply insert "see page x" in the text. Links can be added but then you need the page number pointed to by the link to be added in the margin.

No. this is not bates numbering. The page number to be added in the margin is simply the number of the PDF page where the document hyperlinked to is to be found.

It just seems like it ought to be a relatively simple program to write and there would be a demand for it (albeit in a niche market).

The page width would not need to be widened. It is assumed that the right hand margin is blank and can be stamped over.

By "right hand margin" I just mean close to the right edge of the page. It is assumed that the layout of the contents is such that there is a margin in the sense of a blank space with no text - e.g. like a typical letter or contract. If, unusually, there happens to be existing content right up to the right hand edge then it just gets stamped over.

My area is English law. Most other jurisdictions in the English-speaking world would use similar procedures for court bundles, I would expect. Don't know about the far east.

The link could be anywhere on the page and the page number stamp should be opposite - i.e. on the extreme right, same distance down as the link. There will usually be more than one link on the page.

That is quite complicated and I don't fully understand it.  If I look in the Links pane using PDF X-Change Editor I can see an action of e.g. "Go to a page in the Document: Page 3". I was hoping that there might be a simple solution to just stamp the number (3 in this case) on the right.

I understand the general point - achieving a simple result might involve a degree of complexity in the programming. But, even so, it seems counter-intuitive that stamping the page number could be that complicated. Perhaps you are reading too much into my question. I can't see why it would require "programming allowing for a fantastic amount of variations" and require "many variable strategies".

No. See my comment "It is assumed that the layout of the contents is such that there is a margin in the sense of a blank space with no text - e.g. like a typical letter or contract. If, unusually, there happens to be existing content right up to the right hand edge then it just gets stamped over".

I think you are confusing aim with underlying reason. The aim is just to stamp the linked-to page number in the PDF.

Either the aim of the exercise is for paper where by convention nothing is written in the 1/2" (13mm) outer area or it is for electronic use where a PDF has in page hyperlinks or as images with a link as overlay. the first suggestion was widen the work area so all of those can be allowed for as a printout or image will need extra working width

The PDF (as modified by the stamp) can be printed but there is nothing special which needs to be done to allow it to be printed.

You have the tools to make a working example of a cluttered page to ask in a forum how to avoid the related problems but do use paper to see what I am suggesting is a potential issue when using unknown printers.
